# How do you compare data from two experiments

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am often trying to measure percentage changes under two distinct scenarios/test/period.

An example dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(11)
toy_dat <- data.frame(state = sample(state.name,3, replace=F), 
                 experiment=c('control','measure'), 
                 accuracy=sample(30:50, size=6, replace=T), 
                 speed=sample(21:39, size=6, replace=T)) %>% arrange(state)


     state experiment accuracy speed
1  Alabama    measure       31    24
2  Alabama    control       36    37
3  Indiana    control       30    23
4  Indiana    measure       31    38
5 Missouri    control       50    29
6 Missouri    measure       48    34
```

I then resort to writing something horrible like this:

```
result <- toy_dat %>%  group_by(state) %>% arrange(experiment) %>%
  summarise(acc_delta = (accuracy[2]-accuracy[1])/accuracy[1],
            speed_delta = (speed[2]-speed[1])/speed[1])
```

However, the above solution does not scale at all when the number of measurable begins to grow. In addition, the code is very fragile in terms of the ordering.

I am very new to R. I was hoping that this is a common enough pattern that there are well-known (smarter) solutions to the problem.

I would greatly appreciate any help/pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create your own custom function and use `summarise_each` in order to apply it on all the measurements at once (it doesn't matter how many measurements you have)

```
delta_fun <- function(x) diff(x)/x[1L]

toy_dat %>%  
  group_by(state) %>% 
  arrange(experiment) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(delta_fun), -experiment)

# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
# 
#      state    accuracy      speed
# 1  Alabama -0.13888889 -0.3513514
# 2  Indiana  0.03333333  0.6521739
# 3 Missouri -0.04000000  0.1724138
```

As you mentioned that you are new to R, here's another awesome package you can use in order to achieve the same effect

```
library(data.table)
setDT(toy_dat)[order(experiment), 
               lapply(.SD, delta_fun), 
               .SDcols = -"experiment",
               by = state]
#       state    accuracy      speed
# 1:  Alabama -0.13888889 -0.3513514
# 2:  Indiana  0.03333333  0.6521739
# 3: Missouri -0.04000000  0.1724138
```

Comment: The `summarise_each` function looks very neat. Also, thanks for the data.table solution. I wonder if there is a way to avoid having to use the `x[1L]`-- I fear the `arrange` has to be carefully adjusted depending on how experiment variables are labeled.

Comment: `arrange` has nothing to with how the variables are labeled. It is arranging by `experiment` variable and as long as it stays consistnet, this will work. Otherwise, Im not sure how you expect the function to know which is the measure and which is the control if you will just give it some random labels.

Comment: Sorry should have clarified. `arrange` would behave very differently for say, (control, measure) vs. (june, august) because of lexical ordering. I guess i was hoping(?) for some explicit notation say x['control'] or something. In any case, I am accepting your answer. Thank so much